# Sort list of dictionaries on two criteria

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Recently started programming with python and I have a question to which I cannot come up with an answer. I have a large list of dictionairies with various keys and values (more than below). I want to sort the order of the dictionaries appearing in the list. `list_one`:

```
list_one = [{'country': 'Spain',     'id': 'v1', 'key2': 'value2'},
            {'country': 'France',    'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'},
            {'country': 'China',     'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'},
            {'country': 'Russia',    'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
            {'country': 'Australia', 'id': 'v2', 'key2': 'value2'},
            {'country': 'China',     'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
            ...
           ]
```

First, sort on 'id' value (`v1`, `v2`, `v3`, ...) (which I can work out fine).

Additionally, if `id` values are similar, sort according to the value of the `'country'` key. Bu I do not want to sort these alphabetically. I'd like to be able to sort based on values set to these countries, if that makes sense. So, for example, `France = 1`, `China = 2`, `Australia = 3`, `Spain = 4`, `Russia = 5`.

The ordering of dictionaries should then look as in the second 
example. `list_two`:

```
[{'country': 'Spain',     'id': 'v1', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'Australia', 'id': 'v2', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'China',     'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'Russia',    'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'France',    'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'China',     'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'}
 ...
]
```

Is there a pythonic way to sort the order that those dicts appear in the list, first on the value of the 'id' key, like below, and then on some 'implicit values' set to the countries?

```
list_two = sorted(list_one, key=lambda k: k['id'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Produce a dictionary mapping country name to order number:

```
country_ordering = {'France': 1, 'China': 2, 'Australia': 3,
                    'Spain': 4, 'Russia': 5}
```

then use that in your sort key, returning a tuple with the `id` and a value from that mapping:

```
list_two = sorted(
    list_one, 
    key=lambda k: (k['id'], country_ordering.get(k['country'], float('inf')))
```

I used the `dict.get()` method to look up the ordering value; that way you can specify a default value in case the country is not (yet?) listed in the mapping. Above I used `float('inf')` (*infinity*) as the default value, meaning that any such unlisted countries are sorted at the end (per given `id`).

If you want an exception to be thrown instead, change the  lambda to:

```
lambda k: (k['id'], country_ordering[k['country']])
```

to do a straight key lookup.

Demo:

```
>>> list_one = [{'country': 'Spain',     'id': 'v1', 'key2': 'value2'},
...             {'country': 'France',    'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'},
...             {'country': 'China',     'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'},
...             {'country': 'Russia',    'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
...             {'country': 'Australia', 'id': 'v2', 'key2': 'value2'},
...             {'country': 'China',     'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'}]
>>> country_ordering = {'France': 1, 'China': 2, 'Australia': 3, 'Spain': 4, 'Russia': 5}
>>> sorted(list_one, key=lambda k: (k['id'], country_ordering[k['country']]))
[{'country': 'Spain', 'id': 'v1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'country': 'Australia', 'id': 'v2', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'country': 'China', 'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'country': 'Russia', 'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'country': 'France', 'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'country': 'China', 'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'}]
>>> pprint(_)
[{'country': 'Spain', 'id': 'v1', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'Australia', 'id': 'v2', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'China', 'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'Russia', 'id': 'v3', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'France', 'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'},
 {'country': 'China', 'id': 'v4', 'key2': 'value2'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! One extra question though. What if the ordering on the 'ids' is already correctly done and I only want to re-order those dicts with the same 'countries'?

Comment: @PDavis: You'll have to sort with the full key still. Don't worry about re-sorting in that case, the sorting algorithm Python uses ([*Timsort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)) takes advantage of already-sorted subsections.

Comment: I meant those dicts with the same 'ids', my bad.

Comment: @PDavis: yes, I understood you; yes, you have to re-apply the sort, it's much easier and cheap enough.

Comment: @PDavis: just use the natural sort function in the key? `(extract_number(k['id']), country_ordering[k['country']])` for example.

Comment: @PDavis: The point being that if you can sort on a natural sort (extracting the numeric value) from `id`, you can do the same thing in this extended key.